# Vaciar variables al hacer LogOut en Angular

Tags: angular, local-storage, cache

Tengo unas pantallas que al darle click en un enlace me redirige a otro componente y en este, me carga información correspondiente al dato previo.

Por ejemplo.

Tengo una pantalla paises

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al darle click al Id del país, me redirige a la pantalla de departamentos de este país.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces, la idea es que si regreso a paises, el color del id me cambía para saber qué registros ya he visitado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
navigateTo(id_campo: number) {
    if (!this.service.getpaisesFromCache(id_campo)) { this.service.pushpaisesCacheList(id_campo) }
    this.router.navigate(['../departamentos'], {
      relativeTo: this.route,
      queryParams: { id_campo }
    })
  }

  buttonColor(id_campo: number) {
    return (this.service.getpaisesFromCache(id_campo)) ? 'warn' : 'primary'
  }
```

En el servicio tengo un arreglo donde inserto estos ids cada vez que doy click

```
pushpaisesCacheList(id_campo: number) {
        this.paisesCacheList.push(id_campo)
    }
```

Entonces, la idea es que esto persista en la sesión. Yo puedo moverme por otros componentes y esta variable persiste. Lo que pretendo es que cuando hago un logout se vacíen todas las variables, toda la información. Para que si ingresa otro usuario pues le salga como si no hubiese visitado nada aún.

En la función que me hace el logout hago un localStorage.clear() e igual un sessionStorage.clear().

Sin embargo, hago el logout y me logueo de nuevo, y se mantienen esos ids visitados. Solo se vacían si yo refresco la página.

```
logOut(message = true) {
    this.router.navigate(['/login'])
    // mostrar mensaje
    this.sidenavService.drawerOptions = null
    localStorage.clear()
    sessionStorage.clear()
    if (message) {
      this.sharedService.formActionShowMessage('La sesión ha expirado.', null)
    }
  }
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo vaciar o eliminar el cache de la aplicación al hacer logout?

Comment: Solo necesitar inyectar tu servicio en el componente de logOut. Y luego haces algo como `this._tuServicioCacheList.paisesCacheList = []` Si no quieres hacer publico el arreglo pues crea una función que lo limpie y lo llamas de la misma manera.

Comment: @Angel Pero, ¿qué pasa si no es solo una pantalla la que tiene esta funcionalidad? Puedo tener N pantallas que funcionan de la misma manera. Entonces, ¿tendría que inyectar los servicios de cada componente en el logout?

Comment: Nop, el servicio de `pushpaisesCacheList(id_campo: number) {
        this.paisesCacheList.push(id_campo)
    }` es el que tienes que inyectar en el logout. Si hay varias pantallas todas pueden inyectarse con ese servicio y también lo pones en el logout. De esa manera vacías los datos al ejecutar la función.

Comment: this.service.getpaisesFromCache el contenido de èste service a tù pregunta, recuerda que los services son singleton y pueden mantener su estado.